# What is the difference between pod install and pod install --repo-update?

Tags: cocoapods

What is the difference between `pod install` and `pod install --repo-update`?

It's not clear from this guide:
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there is an existing Podfile.lock that specifies the versions of all requested pods, there is no difference.

If there isn't an existing Podfile.lock, the `--repo-update` will install the latest versions available from the CocoaPods trunk. Without the option, `pod install` will only install the latest versions already available locally.

Comment: I created my own pod. In my podfile, I had the usual stuff pod 'PodName'. When I ran pod install, I was faced with ```Unable to find a specification for `BanyanService```. I thought it was because it needed time to show up, so even after 5 hours I kept getting that message. But strangely, just for no good reason I tried pod install --repo-update instead and it worked, installing my pod but leaving me dumbfounded at what just happened.